# Fatal error running tests: Method on class [com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX] was used outside of a Grails application

Tags: unit-testing, grails

Running Grails 2.4.3 and Hibernate 4:4.3.5.5.  The app runs correctly however when I try to write an integration test it fails without even running the test.

**Error Fatal error running tests: Method on class [com.edocsol.BatchClass] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly. (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [com.edocsol.BatchClass] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.**

BuildConfig.groovy contains:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.7'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"
        compile ':tooltip:0.8'

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

BatchInstance.groovy Domain Object:

```
package com.XXXXXX

class BatchInstance {

    String identifier
    Date creationDate
    Date lastModified
    String batchName
    String currentUser
    String batchStatus
    String uncSubfolder
    String validationOperatorUserName
    BatchClass batchClass
    //    long lockOwner
    //    long remoteBatchInstanceId

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'ephesoft'
        id sqlType: "numeric"
        batchClass column: "batch_class_id", sqlType: "numeric"
        //        lockOwner sqlType: "numeric"
        //                remoteBatchInstanc`eId sqlType: "numeric"
        currentUser column: "curr_user"
        remote column: "is_remote"
        version false
    }

    static belongsTo = BatchClass

    static findAllStatuses() {
        Set set = new HashSet<String>()
        list().each { set += it.batchStatus }
        return set
    }

    String toString () {
        identifier
    }
}
```

Controller Under Test BatchInstanceController.groovy:

```
package com.XXXXXX



import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class BatchInstanceController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
    static scaffold = true

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)

        def c = BatchInstance.createCriteria()
        def results = c.list (params) {
            // If there is a param for batch status filter out based on it
            if(params.batchStatus) {
                eq("batchStatus", params.batchStatus)
            }
        }

        respond results, model:[batchInstanceInstanceCount: results.getTotalCount()]
    }

}
```

Test BatchInstanceControllerIntegrationSpec.groovy located under test/integration:

```
package com.XXXXXX


/**
 *
 */
import grails.test.mixin.*
import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec;
import spock.lang.*

class BatchInstanceControllerIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    BatchInstanceController controller = new BatchInstanceController()

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "Test the index action returns the correct model"() {

                when:"The index action is executed"
                controller.index()

                then:"The model is correct"
                !model.batchInstanceInstanceList
                model.batchInstanceInstanceCount == 0
            }
}
```

Comment: Test class `BatchInstanceControllerIntergrationSpec` is expected to be under `test/integration` and is not supposed to use `@TestFor`.

Comment: Thanks I removed the @TestFor and it is located under the integration testing.